# How to get all available sheets except for some specific ones

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create the code to be getting all sheets in my workbook except for 2 specific ones.
It would be something like I have 17 sheets that I want to parse and 2 extra sheets that I want exclude them by name that I don't need to parse.
I tried this code but it deletes the unwanted sheets while what I need is to remove them from the list that I will then use to loop to parse the remaining correct sheets:

```
Sub Print_all_sheet_names()

' Declare ws as a worksheet object variable.
Dim ws As Worksheet

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Qlik Ingestion").Delete
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dropdown Values").Delete

' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
   MsgBox ws.Name
Next
End Sub
```

Anybody knows how I can be left in the list only with the wanted sheets without deleting the unwanted ones?

Comment: `If ws.name <> "FirstSkipSheet" and ws.name <> "SecondSkipSheet" Then`

Comment: This question is clearly about VBA. Please don't remove that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through all the sheets and check their names

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Qlik Ingestion"
            'Do nothing
        Case "Dropdown Values"
            'Do nothing
        Case Else
             MsgBox ws.Name
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I tried this code `Dim sheets_names_array() As Variant, sheet As Variant


For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
 Select Case ws.Name
   Case "Qlik Ingestion" 
            
        Case "Dropdown Values"
            
        Case "VBmacro"
            
        Case Else
             
             **sheets_names_array.Add (ws.Name)**
    End Select
Next`  but i get an error. basically  I need to push the wanted sheets to an array and then loop through the array

Comment: @Electra - arrays in VBA don't have a `.Add` method.

Comment: thanks @BigBen , I have found documentation online that uses the .Add method. Do you know how to do it without using  the .Add method please?

Comment: Your documentation is not VBA. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays. You'll need to get a count of the sheets that you want, then use `ReDim` to size the array appropriately.